# i am trying to send email through nodemailer, i have permitted my google account for less secure apps, still getiing error

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

I'm trying to send email using nodemailer and below is my code for that...

```
 require('dotenv').config();

const nodemailer=require('nodemailer');

// step 1
let transporter=nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth:{
        user: process.env.EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD
    }
});

let mailOptions={
  from: 'abc@gmail.com',
  to: 'mrinal.annand@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Testing and Testing',
  text: 'yes,it works'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,data){
    if(err)console.log('Error Occurs',err);
    else console.log('Message sent!!');
})
```

i am getting this much long error, what i'm doing wrong here. why it is saying username and password not accepted,both my mails are valid and working, password i have given arbitrarily..

```
Error Occurs Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials x19sm2827077pgk.37 - 
gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1536:34)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:540:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:947:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1536:34)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:540:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:947:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:189:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +     
    '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials x19sm2827077pgk.37 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently the username and password of the email are wrong, you should try to login using copy paste with those credentials

Comment: I have tried that as well, but same error

Comment: Could you please copy and paste your whole code? I see somethings that are lacking but Im not sure if you are omitting them on the post, like this line for example: let nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

Comment: require('dotenv').config();

const nodemailer=require('nodemailer');

// step 1
let transporter=nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth:{
        user: 'amarhutiappa@gmail.com',
        pass: 'Awesome123'
    }
});

let mailOptions={
  from: 'amarhutiappa@gmail.com',
  to: 'mrinal.annand@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Testing and Testing',
  text: 'yes,it works'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,data){
    if(err)console.log('Error Occurs',err);
    else console.log('Message sent!!');
})

Comment: i don't know how to paste this code like i posted in my question, so i just wrote it like a msg. this is the actual code. and i have one more doubt that in the password section, can i provide a password of my own or i should give whatever is the email address password?

Comment: You should give the actual password you use to access gmail. If you make up a password it would not work.

Comment: ok, that means password of sender account, right?

Comment: Please let me know if that fixed the problem

Comment: the problem is fixed, i just swapped the mails and then generated a password key from https://myaccount.google.com/security and applied that password to the code....

Comment: here is the modified code ..->var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'mrinal.annand@gmail.com',
    pass: 'here->the generated key'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'mrinal.annand@gmail.com',
  to: 'amarhutiappa@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Mrinal: Welcome to our site',
  text: 'We will soon get to you'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ');
  }
});

Comment: actually that is a copied code from https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp